# Cannot apply equality in SQL Data Tools scripts "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'" (FIX)

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

Cannot apply equality in SQL Data Tools scripts.
Purpose:  Establish a variable to use as a graceful exit when nothing needs to be done

ERRORS

```
"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'" 
Only assignment, call, increment, decrment, await, and new object expressions can be uses as statement
```

CODE:

```
String recfil=Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::RecfileName"0.Value.ToString();
int recfilExists=Convert.ToInt32(File.Exists(recfil));
bool goodRun = irecfilExists.Equals(1)
bool noRun = irecfilExists.Equals(0)

if (goodRun)
{
Dts.Variables["User::NothingToDo"].Value == goodRun;
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
else
{
Dts.Variables["User::NothingToDo"].Value == noRun;   
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While definitely not the best answer,

```
    if (goodRun || noRun)
      {
            if (goodRun)
            {
               Dts.Variables["User::FileCount"].Value = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               Dts.Variables["User::FileCount"].Value = 0;
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
      }  
   else
      {
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
      }
```

Then in the control flow, added choice function on Success which references the file count as one or zero.  If no files, exit gracefully, otherwise work through the control flow.